# Why won't Phoenix/Plug/Guardian recognize this CSRF token in AJAX calls?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

Protected routes in my Phoenix API are sending 403 responses to requests. Debug logs show:

```
(Plug.CSRFProtection.InvalidCSRFTokenError) invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) token, please make sure that:

  * The session cookie is being sent and session is loaded
  * The request include a valid '_csrf_token' param or 'x-csrf-token' header
```

My router looks like this:

```
defmodule MyWeb.Router do
  use MyWeb, :router
  alias MyWeb.Auth.GuardianPipeline

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug GuardianPipeline
  end

  pipeline :protected do
    plug Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated
    plug :protect_from_forgery
  end

  scope "/api/v1", MyWeb.API.V1, as: :api_v1 do
    pipe_through :api

    post "/login", SessionController, :login
  end

  scope "/api/v1", MyWeb.API.V1, as: :api_v1 do
    pipe_through [:api, :protected]

    delete "/logout", SessionController, :logout
  end
end
```

My session controller login action looks like this:

```
defp login_reply({:ok, user}, conn) do
  conn
  |> Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)
  |> put_session(:_csrf_token, csrf_token)
  |> json(%{csrf_token: get_csrf_token()})
end
```

On the frontend, my request to the protected "logout" path looks like this:

```
const logout = async () => {
  const method = 'DELETE'
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-csrf-token': csrfToken.value
  }
  await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/logout', { method, headers, credentials: 'include' })
```

1. The CSRF error says I should make sure the session is sent and loaded
   I see the session cookie loaded in my browser, so I know it's sent. The session is loaded by the `:fetch_session` plug. So this first condition should be satisfied.
2. The `x-csrf_token` header is being set in the fetch, and I have verified that the `csrfToken.value` matches what was created by `get_csrf_token()`. So the second condition should be satisfied too.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the csrf token validated?

--

Here is the entire JS component

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup (_props) {
    const csrfToken = ref('')
    const email = 'free@city.17'
    const error = ref('')
    const submitting = false

    const isAuthenticated = () => !!csrfToken.value

    const setAuthenticated = () => {
      return isAuthenticated()
    }

    const logout = async () => {
      const method = 'DELETE'
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-csrf-token': csrfToken.value
      }
      await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/logout', { method, headers, credentials: 'include' })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 401) {
            error.value = 'No account found with that email address'
          } else if (!response.ok) {
            error.value = 'Something went wrong'
          }
          return response
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((_err) => {
          error.value = 'network error'
        })

      if (error.value) {
        throw new Error(error.value)
      }

      csrfToken.value = ''
      return true
    }

    const onLogout = () => {
      error.value = ''
      return logout().catch(_e => '')
    }

    const login = async () => {
      const method = 'POST'
      const body = JSON.stringify({ user: { email } })
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/login', { method, headers, body, credentials: 'include' })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 401) {
            error.value = 'No account found with that email address'
          } else if (!response.ok) {
            error.value = 'Something went wrong'
          }
          return response
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((_err) => {
          error.value = 'network error'
        })

      if (error.value) {
        throw new Error(error.value)
      }

      console.log(resp)
      csrfToken.value = resp.csrf_token
      return true
    }

    const onSubmit = () => {
      error.value = ''
      return login().catch(_e => '')
    }

    onMounted(setAuthenticated)

    return {
      csrfToken,
      email,
      error,
      submitting,
      isAuthenticated,
      setAuthenticated,
      onLogout,
      onSubmit
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

The entire Phoenix Session Controller

```
defmodule MyWeb.API.V1.SessionController do
  use MyWeb, :controller
  alias MyWeb.Auth.Guardian
  alias MyWeb.API.V1.Auth

  def login(conn, %{"user" => %{"email" => email}}) do
    Auth.authenticate_user(%{email: email})
    |> login_reply(conn)
  end

  def logout(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> Guardian.Plug.sign_out(clear_remember_me: true)
    |> configure_session(drop: true)
    |> send_resp(:ok, "")
  end

  defp login_reply({:ok, user}, conn) do
    conn
    |> Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)
    # |> Guardian.Plug.remember_me(user)
    |> put_session(:_csrf_token, csrf_token)
    |> json(%{csrf_token: csrf_token})
  end

  defp login_reply({:error, reason}, conn) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:unauthorized)
    |> json(%{reason: reason})
  end
end
```

I created this custom plug for my router's `protected` pipeline:

```
  defp inspect_plug(conn, _opts) do
    IO.inspect(Plug.Conn.get_session(conn), label: :session)

    session_token = Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, "_csrf_token")
    IO.inspect(session_token, label: :session_token)
    IO.inspect(byte_size(session_token), label: :session_token_size)
    csrf_token = Plug.CSRFProtection.dump_state_from_session(session_token)

    IO.inspect(csrf_token, label: :csrf_token)

    conn
  end
```

Here's an example of what it logs on "logout" requests:

```
session: %{
  "_csrf_token" => "HSwrOF5AOQ5nKyIWHH9RFFg0HVMWDRA_dFIVlulMQipLw39PmPzkPXIf",
  "guardian_default_token" => "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJhdXRvbWVldHVwIiwiZXhwIjoxNjI2NDU1MDQ4LCJpYXQiOjE2MjQwMzU4NDgsImlzcyI6ImF1dG9tZWV0dXAiLCJqdGkiOiJkMDczYTMwZi00ZTMzLTRkZjItODBhMi04YzRkZDNiYzAzMzAiLCJuYmYiOjE2MjQwMzU4NDcsInN1YiI6IjEiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.KF-rv-65G_0NUMsFa9tYedWKE0gRTd9hvx_pOyBHFV5DTGFPtsfJnaz3WOk63ARKu8-bEbjAZGXRRPAZ0E3LMw"
}
session_token: "HSwrOF5AOQ5nKyIWHH9RFFg0HVMWDRA_dFIVlulMQipLw39PmPzkPXIf"
session_token_size: 56
csrf_token: nil
```

I'm wondering why `Plug.CSRFProtection.dump_state_from_session` is returning nil from my `_csrf_token` session cookie.

https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/fa579592ebf53306e3a4b13e2414a40997add1f7/lib/plug/csrf_protection.ex#L195

Comment: I don't see the handoff between the JSON response returned by `login_reply` and where your page's JS reads this value and sends it back.  Where is your `csrfToken` variable being set?  I think you need to include a bit more of your JS.
Have you tried using Postman or curl to send a request (just to verify that everything works when a properly formatted request is sent)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Everett. The csrfToken variable is being set by the JS after receiving the response to the login request. I've omitted it here for clarity/brevity because there is too much machinery in place to share concisely, and it's just a distraction anyway. I've confirmed that the csrfToken value is definitely being set correctly and sent along in the x-csrf-token header in the logout request.

Comment: And can you craft a request using Postman or curl that works?  I also don't see exactly where your `login_reply` is getting called.  My guess is that somewhere in the "too much machinery" is where you're losing things and that simplifying this for the case of the question here would help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions. The fetch request works just fine, so I'm not sure what postman or curl would have to add to that. I can inspect the network request using my browser's dev tools, as well as with Iex,pry and IO.inspect on the Phoenix side. The "too much machinery" is just a Vue component; there's really nothing relevant to the question that's not shown here. I'm certain the issue lies somewhere in relation to the Plug.CSRFProtection or Phoenix's wrapper of it, but I don't understand where or how.

Comment: I've added the entirety of the JS to the question

Comment: I've added the entirety of the session controller to the question

Comment: It's tough to debug.  If you remove the `:protected` from the relevant `pipe_thru` does the request work?  Can you inspect it? And, are there some options that should be set when you use Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated? https://hexdocs.pm/guardian/Guardian.Plug.EnsureAuthenticated.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233939/discussion-between-vaer-k-and-everett).